# Bing Map return inconsistent result

Tags: bing-maps

I have used [Bing MAP API](http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/US/%7B0%7D%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%7B3%7D?o=xml%7B4%7Dkey=%7B5%7D)

With Basic Key for Non-Profit organization.

Above API given inconsistent result with “**200**” status code and “**OK**” status description.

Some time it gives Estimated Total 0 without any other tags and some time it gives Estimated Total 1 with all Locations.

Try this [example](http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/US/FL/34232/Sarasota/2529%20Rustic%20Oak%20Ct?o=xml&key=Aq0SOyHGZcgRcsToZUrM5wjZwewFkY9Ys1BKmAzJ-wqOmoJ193Dn2JASWuDtkd9o).

Answer (score 0):

Martijn Pieters - An identical answer was added as Stackoverflow couldn't find the other answered question, even though I had it open in another tab. Thus, I reposted the answer so the question asker could get an answer.